# How to change Stream-based widget to GetX widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, provider, flutter-getx

Hi I am trying to implement a stopwatch widget with GetX Package.

I am referencing stop_watch_timer package from pub.dev.

The following is the source code of my implementation and the source code of stop_watch_timer package.

My Implementation:

```dart
var _elapsedTime = 0.obs;
  var _rawTimeController = 0.obs;
  var _secondTimeController = 0.obs;
  var _minuteTimeController = 0.obs;
  var _recordsController = <StopWatchRecord>[].obs;

  int get rawTime => _rawTimeController.value;
  int get secondTime => _secondTimeController.value;
  int get minuteTime => _minuteTimeController.value;
  List<StopWatchRecord> get records => _recordsController;
```

Reference:

```
  final PublishSubject<int> _elapsedTime = PublishSubject<int>();

  final BehaviorSubject<int> _rawTimeController =
      BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);
  ValueStream<int> get rawTime => _rawTimeController;

  final BehaviorSubject<int> _secondTimeController =
      BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);
  ValueStream<int> get secondTime => _secondTimeController;

  final BehaviorSubject<int> _minuteTimeController =
      BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);
  ValueStream<int> get minuteTime => _minuteTimeController;

  final BehaviorSubject<List<StopWatchRecord>> _recordsController =
      BehaviorSubject<List<StopWatchRecord>>.seeded([]);
  ValueStream<List<StopWatchRecord>> get records => _recordsController;
```

I am not quite sure if I am doing it right.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!